# Are there any visual differences between WKWebView and UIWebView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to migrate away from the deprecated UIWebView in Xamarin Forms iOS, and I read online that WKWebView is now the default in Xamarin Forms 4.x, and I was currently in 3.6.0.x.

So I decided to update hoping that the Webview would automatically update for me, but I realized there is no way to tell because I don't know what, and if there even is a difference in how the webviews look. I've looked online but can't find any side by side pictures of the same app/interface using WK vs. UI. Is there a difference at all?

The only difference I saw after updating, was that on one of the pages, the loading icon wouldn't disappear whereas it did after a couple of seconds in UI.

Thanks!

Comment: UIWebView will be deprecated that is why Xamarin is pushing to make WKWebView to be default. When we submit ios release to appstore,  we get a notification or warning that soon binaries will get rejected due to usage of UIWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

The easiest way to answer this question is simply going to be to test it. To my knowledge, both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` use the exact same underlying WebKit code/engine to render HTML content. There may be differences due to separate defaults and properties that one has vs. the other, but for the most part, they should be identical. But you shouldn't take my word for it! If you can, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! And I did give it a try! Do you mean trying to run it before and after I updated Xamarin Forms? To see if it switched from UI to WK? I did that, and as I mentioned the loading icon was the only difference, if there was a difference at all does that confirm that my app switched from UI to WK? 

If not, how can I test it? I was thinking of ways to see if my app is now using WK but I don't really know how to because I'm new to this stuff, and especially if they are identical in looks like you said. Do you have any advice on that? @mattsven

Comment: After a short search I find this: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/3346 It describes exactly what you need to do to make sure you're using `WKWebView`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I had to add that line into my project, thank you!